# Проблемы с вычислениями в C#

Tags: c#

Почему в С# -71%26 = -19?
При том что в других языках как например Python, -71%26 = 7

Comment: Потому что питон кривой) В JS например тоже -19

Comment: `$ python -c 'print(-(71%26))'` → `-19`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Такова реализация. Вообще, всего существует по меньшей мере [5 способов нахождения модуля от числа](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation).

В C# используется усеченное деление для нахождения остатка.

Об этом явно указано и в [документации к языку](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/arithmetic-operators#remainder-operator-):

> Знак ненулевого остатка такой же, как и у левого операнда

Если вам нужно, чтобы вычислялось с условием `0 <= r < n`, где `r` - остаток, `n` - делитель, можно написать:

```
//вариант 1:
var r = (b + a % b) % b;

//вариант 2:
var r = a % b;
if (r < 0)
   r = r + b; // или же краткой записью: r += b
```

Comment: Думаю автор спрашивал не про знак, а про результат в виде самого числа

Comment: @helloworld это ведь одно и то же в данном контексте, нет?

Comment: Спасибо большое, помогло.

Comment: @MaxS странно, просто результат `(26 + 71 % 26) % 26;`  будет 19 а не 7. Там наверное должно быть `26 - ` а не `26 + ` ?

Comment: @helloworld так там и будет `(26 - 71 % 26) % 26`, потому что `a = -71`

Comment: @MaxS у вас в ответе +  в итоге первый вариант даёт ответ 19

Comment: @helloworld у меня в ответе написано ... ***+ a*** % b ... Если a < 0, то, раскрыв формулу, получим минус.

Comment: То есть `if` надо применять в любом случае, хоть это `var r = (b + a % b) % b;` хоть это `var r = a % b;`? А то сейчас кажется что `if` относится только ко второму варианту, т.к. он там описан

Comment: @helloworld if относится только ко второму варианту. Первый вариант самодостаточен. Введите `var a = -71; var b = 26;` и подумайте, что будет написано в формуле из первого варианта при подстановке значений a и b.

Comment: Вам не кажется странным, что при -71 ответ будет 7, а при 71 ответ будет 19? Хотя ответ в любом случае должен давать остаток 7.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141410/discussion-between-max-s-and-hello-world).

Comment: Я кажется понял, я не туда смотрел))